# When an application is closed or not in use, I want to continue sending data to the server. Does it work in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm uploading data to a server, and I want to continue doing so even if the app is closed or not in use. How can I do this in Flutter?

Sending data to a server after the Flutter app has been terminated necessitates a combination of background processing techniques and, possibly, a push mechanism to wake up the app when necessary. Flutter does not directly support executing code while the app is closed.

Comment: Look at this package. Seems like it'll helkp you https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Comment: workmanager is not working

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course its possible in flutter, you just need to implement a background/foreground service and you will be able to run your code after the app gets closed.
there are some nice packages there intended for such a need:
[flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) and
[flutter_foreground_task](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task)
also you can use [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package(or any other) to implement your custom notification to let user know there is a task running in the background.
there's also a package called [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager), (from docs):"Additionally, the WorkManager plugin enables persistent background processing that keeps tasks scheduled through app restarts and system reboots."